# Automator service in OSX High Sierra

Tags: macos, automator

Automator service at the active finder window. The idea is to create a folder template at the active finder window with choosing the new folder 
dialog.
Service:[image]

1. ask for folder name
2. make new folder
3. run shell script

The Automator service fails and I am not sure why. The path of the active finder window is not reaching the variable thePath which is assigned to the new folder Automator action.

The screen shots displays a simplified version of the service and the error.
Can I get idea of what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you explicitly **return** the path in the AppleScript action? And if the Finder is supposed to create the folder return the `alias` rather than a POSIX path.

Comment: I was trying to return the active finder window path to the variable and assign the variable to the new folder action in Automator.  But my workflow failed. The replay below accomplished what I was trying to achieve. Thanks fro your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting this code in a run AppleScript action, into your workflow.

```
set theName to text returned of (display dialog ¬
    "INSERT A NEW FOLDER NAME" default answer ¬
    "Enter Desired Name Of New Folder" hidden answer false ¬
    buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} ¬
    default button ¬
    "OK" cancel button ¬
    "Cancel" with title ¬
    "CHOOSE A NAME" with icon 1 ¬
    giving up after 30)

tell application "Finder"
    set currentTarget to target of window 1 as alias
    set the name of (make new folder at currentTarget) to theName
end tell
```

[image]